# npm install issue in Mac M1 model

Tags: node.js, npm-install

I am trying to install npm in Mac m1 model but I keep getting the below error and I tried npm install --force but still error keeps occurring.

```
npm ERR! path /Users/anishbabu/Documents/platform/node_modules/zeromq
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- (shx test -f ./script/build.js || run-s build.js) && cross-env npm_config_build_from_source=true node-gyp-build
npm ERR! dlopen(/Users/anishbabu/Documents/platform/node_modules/zeromq/prebuilds/darwin-arm64/node.napi.glibc.node, 0x0001): Library not loaded: '/Users/runner/arm-target/opt/libsodium/lib/libsodium.23.dylib'
npm ERR!   Referenced from: '/Users/anishbabu/Documents/platform/node_modules/zeromq/prebuilds/darwin-arm64/node.napi.glibc.node'
npm ERR!   Reason: tried: '/Users/runner/arm-target/opt/libsodium/lib/libsodium.23.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libsodium.23.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libsodium.23.dylib' (no such file)
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.13.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.11.0 found at "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@18/18.13.0_1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/anishbabu/Documents/platform/node_modules/zeromq/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@18/18.13.0_1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/anishbabu/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.13.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/Users/anishbabu/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.13.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@18/18.13.0_1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/Users/anishbabu/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.13.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/anishbabu/Documents/platform/node_modules/zeromq',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! Package libsodium was not found in the pkg-config search path.
npm ERR! Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libsodium.pc'
npm ERR! to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
npm ERR! No package 'libsodium' found
npm ERR! gyp: Call to 'pkg-config libsodium --libs' returned exit status 1 while in binding.gyp. while trying to load binding.gyp
npm ERR! gyp ERR! configure error 
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `gyp` failed with exit code: 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onCpExit (/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@18/18.13.0_1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/configure.js:284:16)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@18/18.13.0_1/bin/node" "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/node@18/18.13.0_1/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/anishbabu/Documents/platform/node_modules/zeromq
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.13.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve it only by running this:

```
npm install -g cross-env
brew install pkg-config
brew install libsodium
brew install zeromq
brew install cmake
```